# Unable to set ViewController's title in Delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, page-title

I have implemented an optionTable with stores a list of options for my app to execute

I have defined a protocol method within the option table so that the main table knows when the user has selected an option

```
//Protocol defined in **OPTIONSTABLEVIEW**
@protocol OptionsTableDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didSelectOption:(NSString *)option withtitleString:(NSString*)titleString;

@end

//Set the delegate property
@interface OptionsTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    id optionTableDelegate;
}

@end
```

This delegate method is triggered after the user selects an option in the optionstableview

```
//User selects an option and the delegate method is triggered
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) 
    {
        case OPTION_LATEST:
            self.option = @"for_you";
            self.titleString = [self.optionsArray objectAtIndex:OPTION_LATEST];
            break;

        case OPTION_RANDOM:
            self.option = @"random";
            self.titleString = [self.optionsArray objectAtIndex:OPTION_RANDOM];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

//Delegate method triggered to return the option and title string to the main table
[self.optionTableDelegate didSelectOption:self.option withtitleString:self.titleString];
}
```

In the main table (calling options table) I setup the options table delegate to self and also included the delegate method

```
//Main table **QUESTIONTABLEVIEWCONTROLLER**
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set up options tableview
    self.optionsTableHeight = 24 + (44*2);
    CGRect optionsTableFrame = CGRectMake(0, -optionsTableHeight, 320, optionsTableHeight);
    OptionsTableView *tempOptionsTable = [[OptionsTableView alloc]initWithFrame:optionsTableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.optionsTableView = tempOptionsTable;

    //Setting the delegate to self
    self.optionsTableView.optionTableDelegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.optionsTableView];
}
```

And I tried to set the page title in the delegate method of the main table

```
//Delegate method in main table
-(void)didSelectOption:(NSString *)option withtitleString:(NSString *)titleString
{
    //Set title here (doesn't work)
    self.title = titleString;
    NSLog(@"title :%@",self.title);
    self.type = option;

    [self.optionsTableView slideOptionsTableOut];

    [self getData];

}
```

The title of my page doesn't get change in the above delegate method. Any advise on how I can change the title after selecting the option in the options table?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make one of two:

1) Replace `[self.optionTableDelegate didSelectOption:self.option withtitleString:self.titleString];` with `[self didSelectOption:self.option withtitleString:self.titleString];`

2) Replace `self.optionsTableView.optionTableDelegate = self;` with `self.optionTableDelegate = self;`

Comment: I was thrown errors in both cases. 1)Error: Method '-didSelectOption:withTitleString' not found. 2)Error: Property 'optionTableDelegate'not found on object...

Comment: Then I don't understand why you can call `[self.optionTableDelegate didSelectOption:self.option withtitleString:self.titleString];`? So `self.self.optionTableDelegate` exist?

Comment: I updated the question. Essentially I set the delegate property "optionTableDelegate" in the .h file of the OptionsTableView. Hence in OptionsTableVIew, I just call [self.optionTableDelegate didSelect...]; I thought that the only way to call my protocol method is through the delegate property?

Comment: Ok, now I see. You are using delegate correctly (but I'll advice to define `id< OptionsTableDelegate > optionTableDelegate;`). Does `NSLog(@"title :%@",self.title);` print something to console?

Comment: yes the value is correct. it just seems that the self.title is not being refreshed. i tried to push another view onto the stack and then after cming back, the title is changed. any idea how i can refresh the navbar title?

Comment: And what is `self` in that case? `self.title` -  I don't understand what is `title`. What is the type of class `self`?

Comment: self is my mainTableViewController. I am calling the optionsTableView from my mainTableViewController. My understanding is that to set title of a view controller, you can simply use self.title = @"some title"

Comment: Try `self.navigationItem.title = @"some title";`

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. I need to refresh it when I set the new title. Nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use      `[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Your Title"];`
    to update the title of your navBar.